# Set up Ubuntu/Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, nginx, laravel-5

We have set up a local server on one of our branches. Ubuntu for OS and Nginx for Web server. Our target is to access our projects or websites by using this format http://Ip_address/Folder_Name. Like http://192.168.1.1/myproject1 and http://192.168.1.1/myproject2. 
We have accomplished that target with the configuration below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name _;
        location /myproject1 {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /myproject1/public/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }
        location /myproject2 {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /myproject2/public/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }
        location /myproject3 {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /myproject3/public/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }
        location /myproject4 {
            try_files $uri $uri/ myproject4/public/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }
    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

The main problem is anyone can access the .env file as well as the other file that can be found in my root folder (.env , .htaccess , etc).We are using a Laravel framework to complete all the project. File can be downloaded via "http://192.168.1.1/myproject1/.env". What is the best way to prevent the user from downloading any of my files? I don't know if we missed something on our configuration or what.